# Javascript mystery: variables in functions

Tags: javascript, function

OK, I'm stumped, mainly because I don't use javascript enough. I know this is an array pointer problem (I must have to copy the array in the function...), but not sure how to fix it. Can I trouble you for an explanation why my Javascript version doesn't work and the Python version does? It is supposed to reverse an array (I know there is a built-in), but my question is: How are arrays in Javascript treated differently than in Python?

```
Javascript (does not work): 

function reverseit(x) {

  if (x.length == 0) { return ""};
  found = x.pop();
  found2 = reverseit(x);
  return  found + " " + found2 ;

};

var out = reverseit(["the", "big", "dog"]);

// out == "the the the"
```

==========================

```
Python (works):

def reverseit(x):
    if x == []: 
        return ""
    found = x.pop()
    found2 = reverseit(x)
    return  found + " " + found2

out = reverseit(["the", "big", "dog"]);

// out == "dog big the"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should be...

```
  var found = x.pop();
  var found2 = reverseit(x);
```

Without localizing these variables you'll declare them as global ones - and rewrite their values each time `reverseit` is called. By the way, these errors can be prevented with `'use strict';` directive ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode)), if it's supported by the developer's browser (and it should be, in my opinion).

Obviously the code works in Python because `found` and `found2` *are* local there.

But look at the bright side of JS life: you could just write that function like this:

```
function reverseit(x) {
  return x.length 
         ? x.pop() + " " + reverseit(x) 
         : "";
};
console.log(reverseit(['the', 'big', 'dog']));
```

... without declaring any local variables at all.

Comment: Yes; thanks! That explains a lot! 

And it shows that it has nothing to do with an array -- my error there. 

It seems a bit odd that what is inside a function should ever be global... but with the proper syntax checker, I suppose that could be flagged so that newbies like me don't get tripped up. 

Thanks for the quick response.